# Why does MDN recommend sandboxing uploading files to a different (sub)domain?

Tags: html, forms, security

Mozilla Development Network [recommends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) sandboxing uploaded files to a different subdomain:

> Sandbox uploaded files (store them on a different server and allow
>   access to the file only through a different subdomain or even better
>   through a fully different domain name).

I don't understand what additional security this would provide; my approach has been to upload files on the same domain as the web page with the `<input>` form control, restrict uploaded files to a particular directory and perform antivirus scans on them, and then allow access to them on the same domain they were uploaded to.

Answer (score 1):

There's practical/performance reasons and security reasons.

From a practical/performance reason, unless you are on a budget, store your files on a system optimised for performance. This can be any type of CDN if you are serving them once uploaded, or just isolated upload-only servers. You can do this yourself, or better off you can use something like AWS S3 and customise the permissions to your needs.

From a security point of view, it is incredibly hard to protect an uploaded file from being executable, specially if you are using a server side scripting language. There are many methods, both in HTTP and in the most popular HTTP servers (nginx, apache, ...) to harden things and make them secure, but there is so many things that you have to take into account and another bunch that you would never even think about, that it is much safer to just leave your files somewhere else altogether, ideally where there's no scripting engine that could run script code on them.

I assume that the different subdomain or domain recommendation is about XSS, vulns exploiting bad configurations of CORS, prevention on phishing attempts (like someone successfully uploading content to your site that mimics your site but does something nasty such as stealing user credentials or providing fake information, and the site would still be served from your domain and there wouldn't be an https security alert from the certificate either).